# Base entity class. NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, interface, entity

Would it be a good practice to implement entity base class like that:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Entity<T> : IComparable<Entity<T>>, IFormattable
{
    public abstract Int32 CompareTo(Entity<T> entity);
    public abstract String ToString(String format, IFormatProvider provider);

    // ...
}
```

So all derived classes must implement those interfaces.
Is it reasonable to put `IComparable<T>` interface on entity class?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a *good* (or *bad*) practice - it comes down entirely to your needs.

Specifying `IComparable` at such as general level comes with the risk that it may not make sense to compare some objects further down in the inheritance chain. Even if you can compare two objects, would it always make sense to? You may be requiring lines of code to be written to satify a contract which would never be used - beware of [YAGNI circumstances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

However, this would be fine if you need to create an absolute contract so that any objects inheriting from Entity can be compared. This allows you to make positive assumptions in your code.

Answer (score 2):

What would T be? Your domain class? If that's the case why not make the Entity class non-generic and directly inherit from Entity?

In general, I've found it to be a good practice to derive all domain classes that can be handled by a particular Repository from a common interface or base class. This allows the Repository to be generic to that interface, providing compile-time checking that you are attempting to use the Repository to persist something that the Repository has mapped.  If you use a base class, though, don't map it unless you need a way to uniquely identify any Entity regardless of its actual subclass type; otherwise you'll get that Entity table (with any common fields) as a table in your DB and it can become difficult to manually trace through your data layer.

However, a common, mapped Entity may be desireable; you may want to uniquely identify Persons and Companies by a common ID column that is unique even through Persons and Companies are saved to different tables.

Here's a sterilized example of the hierarchy I've used in one of my projects:

```
//identifies a class as persistable, and requires the class to specify 
//an identity column for its PK
public interface IDomainObject { long Id {get;} } 

//In a repository-per-DB model, just because it's an IDomainObject doesn't mean
//a repo can work with it. So, I derive further to create basically "marker"
//interfaces identifying domain objects as being from a particular DB:
public interface ISecurityDomainObject:IDomainObject { }
public interface IDataDomainObject:IDomainObject { }
public interface IData2DomainObject:IDomainObject { }

//There may be logic in your repo or DB to prevent certain concurrency issues.
//You can specify that a domain object has the necessary fields for version-checking
//either up at the IDomainObject level, a lower level, or independently:
public interface IVersionedDomainObject:IDomainObject
{ 
   long Version {get;}
   string LastUpdatedBy {get;}
   DateTime LastUpdatedDate {get;}
}

//Now, you can use these interfaces to restrict a Repo to a particular subset of
//the full domain, based on the DB each object is persisted to:

public interface IRepository<TDom> where TDom:IDomainObject 
{
    //yes, GTPs can be used as GTCs
    T GetById<T>(long Id) where T:TDom;
    void Save<T>(T obj) where T:TDom;

    //not only must the domain class for SaveVersioned() implement TRest,
    //it must be versionable
    void SaveVersioned<T>(T versionedObj) where T:TDom, IVersionedDomainObject
}

//and now you can close TDom to an interface which restricts the concrete
//classes that can be passed to the generic methods of the repo:

public class ISecurityRepo:IRepository<ISecurityDomainObject> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your entities require comparability and formatting than using a base class is a very good practice. 
sometimes the identity field is also implemented in the base class.

Comment: Yes, I know about keeping an Id (the class above is defined generic so it can use wheter Int32 or Guid type of an id) and overridng/implementing `Equals` method. And, Thanks!